# Audio Stream not added to a video

Tags: ffmpeg

I use ffmpeg to add two audio files to a video, when I do the following command :

```
ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i audio1.mp3 -i audio2.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]adelay=5000|5000;[1][2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy output.mp4
```

I get a video with only sound from audio1.mp3, but when I import only one audio, I get sound from the imported audio file (audio1.mp3 or audio2.mp3), all audio files have sound.

My question is how to get the two sounds in output video?

Comment: you can try to add `-map 2:a`

Comment: `adelay` filter has no named output. Try: `"[1]adelay=5000|5000[a1];[a1][2]amix=inputs=2[a]"`

Comment: @Rotem I get "Filter amix has an unconnected output"

Comment: Try: `ffmpeg -an -i video.mp4 -i audio1.mp3 -i audio2.mp3 -filter_complex "[1]adelay=5000|5000[a1];[a1][2]amix=inputs=2[a]" -map 0:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy output.mp4` (the connected output of `amix=inputs=2[a]` is `-map "[a]"`). Are you sure?

Comment: @Rotem the code in last comment works. thank you!